# Notice: Undefined property: UserController::$view in

Tags: php

I have two files, a controller and a class with functions in to render a page

```
<?php

class View
{

 public function render($filename, $data = null)
{
    if ($data) {
        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            $this->{$key} = $value;
        }
    }

    require Config::get('PATH_VIEW') . '_templates/header.php';
    require Config::get('PATH_VIEW') . $filename . '.php';
    require Config::get('PATH_VIEW') . '_templates/footer.php';
}
```

Inside my controller, I am trying to render the page as follows:

```
public function profile(){
$this->view->render('user/profile');
}
```

But I am getting:

> Notice: Undefined property: UserController::$view

and

> Fatal error: Call to a member function render() on a non-object in

The render is working on my other controllers but not my usercontroller class which this post is about...

Am I clashing controllers or models?

Comment: I'm not sure if you have to include view in `$this->view->render('user/profile');`. Try to change for this one: `$this->render('user/profile');` or this one: `$this->[your_model]->render('user/profile');` and check if you are having the same or different problem

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined method UserController::render()

Comment: hmmm.... since UsersController trying to call another class diferent with its model. try to add `require()` or `include()` function for View Class

Comment: Get a grip. UserController does not have a `view` property because you have not instantiated the View Class anywhere in UserController

Comment: Ever heard of an autoload?

Answer (score 0):

I was initiating it like:

```
$this->view->Render('page');
```

Rather than

```
$this->View->Render('page');
```

Classes are case sensitive (in my case, or in general), make sure you match it case for case.

I have fixed it now.